# jenkins で、シェルの中から複数行の環境変数を設定するには？

Tags: jenkins

jenkins の、シェルの実行において計算された結果を、その後の処理 (後続ジョブのトリガパラメータであったり、拡張 E-mail の本文に仕込ませたり) で利用するために、ジョブの環境変数に注入したい場合があります。

EnvInject のプラグインを使えば、単純な文字列であるならば、プロパティファイルを経由して、環境変数を注入できることはわかったのですが、複数行のテキスト(つまり、改行を含む)を環境変数として注入する方法がわかりません。

これはどうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

使ったこと無いので的はずれかもしれませんが

[EnvInject Plugin - Jenkins - Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)

> Known limitations
>
> ```
> Properties values can't end with backslashes in the properties content section
> (interpreted as content with multiple lines)
> ```

とあるので 末尾が`\`の場合は改行とみなすような気がします。

HOGEHOGE = hello \
mr. \
jenkins.

Comment: この、 known limitations は、どこからの引用か、聞いてもいいでしょうか。

Comment: [EnvInject Plugin - Jenkins - Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) こちらです

Answer (score 0):

拡張 E-mail の本文にシェルの計算結果を仕込ませるには、 FILE トークンを使った方が楽であることに気がつきました。

```
${FILE,path="path/to/result-file"}
```